# How can I add images/diagrams to API Blueprint?

Tags: image, apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

We would like to integrate images into our API documentation on Apiary, as a way of documenting the underlying application architecture or to illustrate sample workflows/sequence diagrams. However, a search through [Apiary documentation](https://docs.apiary.io/) and the [API Blueprint Specification](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md) don't seem to yield any results on how this can be done.

Is it possible to add images to API Blueprint? Or do these images have to be hosted externally and referenced by URL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

David - API Blueprint is based on Markdown syntax (as are many other places including GitHub comments). You can use the following syntax to insert an image into Markdown (and API Blueprint):

`![name](/url)`

These images indeed need to be hosted externally and referenced via URL.

Comment: Do we have access to the dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

As described in another answer:

```
![alternative text](/url)
```

Or on linux for a local image:

```
![alternative text](./image.png)
```

but if you want to specify the image size, use html directly

```
<img src="image.png" alt="image alternative text" width="500"/>
```